# How to override a method in dojox _Scroller class?

Tags: grid, methods, overriding, dojo

How do I override a method in dojox.grid._Scroller class from a class extending dojox.grid.DataGrid.

dojox.grid.DataGrid extends dojox.grid._Grid, which requires dojox.grid._Scroller. The method of interest here is: getScrollBottom(inTop).
Thanks in advance!

David

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [dojo.extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154927/how-to-override-a-method-in-dojox-scroller-class)

```
 dojo.require('dojox.grid._Scroller');
 dojo.extend(dojox.grid._Sroller, {
    methodToOverride: function() {
      // good times here
    }
 };
```